# how to calculate PSNR value in case of random valued impulse noise?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have image corrupted by random impulse noise. I do filtering with standard median filter and get filtered image. I have original and filtered image. Now I want to calculate PSNR of image. I tried as below but getting error image. Please have a look and tell me what I did wrong?

```
ip1=imread(a,'bmp');                  
I = im2double(ip1); 
p = 0.1;    
Ir = (I + p*rand(size(I)))/(1+p);
I1=im2uint8(Ir);  
ip=medfilt2(I1);
imshow(ip);
[peaksnr, snr] = psnr(ip, ip1);
```

It giving filtered image but have error for calculating PSNR.
ERROR : > ??? Undefined function or method 'psnr' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
Error in ==>[peaksnr, snr] = psnr(ip, ip1);
What wrong I did?

Comment: What output does `which psnr` return?

Comment: peaksnr = psnr(A,ref) calculates the peak signal-to-noise ratio for the image A, with the image ref as the reference. A and ref must be of the same size and class. source : http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/psnr.html

Comment: I meant for you to type `which psnr` into Matlab, and to tell what output that command produces.

Comment: ?? I am not getting your comment. I want to calculate PSNR for filtered image ip. I found that there is direct command for calculating it. So I used psnr(ip,ip1) as i got to know from the link i posted. but its giving error.

Comment: Yes, and I am asking you to verify what output `which psnr` produces to make sure you have that function available. If you look at the PSNR documentation, you'll note that it was introduced in R2014a. So you will not have it if you are using any earlier version of Matlab.

Comment: ohh I have matlab 7.9.0(R2009b)